# Can mount CIFS share but not read / write to it

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mount, hyper-v, cifs

I have a GNU/Linux (Xubuntu) guest running in Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Pro Host. I'm trying to mount a folder shared by a host locally. What seems strange to me is that I can mount the folder but not read from or write to it.

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.3/codebase codebase -o username=myUsername,password=myPassword,iocharset=utf8,uid=root,gid=root,rw
```

This appears to succeed. If I run mount it displays this amongst the output:

```
//192.168.0.3/codebase on /home/myBox/codebase type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=default,cache=strict,username=myUsername,domain=,uid=0,forceuid,gid=0,forcegid,addr=192.168.0.3,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

However, trying to do anything with that mount point, ls, touch, mkdir, chmod, chown, whatever, all returns "Permission Denied". The permissions of the directory read as "drwxr-xr-x 2 root root". I am root when I try these operations.

I originally had vers=3.1.1 as one of the options on the mount command but this causes the mount to fail with "mount error(11): Resource temporarily unavailable".

I have another Guest VM in Hyper-V this time running Windows 10, that is able to connect. Originally this caused a problem because the host will only allow the same set of credentials to connect from a single other machine, but I have secondary credentials for the GNU/Linux box so that's not the issue. The Host is sharing the folder with permissions for "Everyone" to read/write.

If I change either the username or the password when mounting, it fails with permission denied so I am taking it that my credentials are correct. The guest can ping the host and get a reply.

I don't understand why it can mount the folder but not read from it. Help?